# how to deduce the return type of a function in template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, types, bind

I am trying to write a template class named Binder that bind functions and parameters as whole, distinguished by the returning type of the binded function, this is my approach:

```
template <typename return_type>
class Binder
{
    public:
        virtual return_type call() {}
};
```

invoking `call` will invoke some pre-binded functions with parameters, and return the result.
I want some template classes inherited from Binder that do the real binding job.
below is a one-parameter-function binding class:

```
template<typename func_t, typename param0_t>
class Binder_1 : public Binder< ***return_type*** > 
        // HOW TO DETERMINE THE RETURN TYPE OF func_t? 
        // decltype(func(param0)) is available when writing call(),
        // but at this point, I can't use the variables...
{
    public:
        const func_t &func;
        const param0_t &param0;

        Binder_1 (const func_t &func, const param0_t &param0)
            : func(func), param0(param0) {}

        decltype(func(param0)) call()
        {
            return func(param0);
        }            
}
// Binder_2, Binder_3, ....
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
template<typename func_t, typename param0_t>
Binder_1<func_t, param0_t> bind(const func_t &func, const param0_t &param0)
{
    reurn Binder_1<func_t, param0_t>(func, param0);
}

// ... `bind` for 2, 3, 4, .... number of paramters

int func(int t) { return t; }

double foo2(double a, double b) { return a > b ? a : b; }
double foo1(double a) { return a; }
int main()
{
    Binder<int> int_binder = bind(func, 1);
    int result = int_binder.call(); // this actually calls func(1);

    Binder<double> double_binder = bind(foo2, 1.0, 2.0);
    double tmp = double_binder.call(); // calls foo2(1.0, 2.0);
    double_binder = bind(foo1, 1.0);
    tmp = double_binder.call(); // calls foo1(1.0)
}
```

can `bind` function in boost library be adapted to achieve this functionality?
similar solutions are welcome too!

Comment: what functionality are you trying to achieve? Just binding functions to parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Introducing [`std::declval<T>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval).

This is a dummy function declared as:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval();

// This means it returns T&& if T is no a reference 
//                     or T& if T is already a reference
```

and never actually defined.

It is therefore only to be used within unevaluated contexts such as `sizeof` or... `decltype`!

With this, you get:

```
template<typename func_t, typename param0_t>
class Binder_1: public Binder<decltype(std::declval<func_t>()(std::declval<param0_t>())>
```

It is a bit verbose, but hey! It works :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [`result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

Comment: `template < typename func_t, typename param0_t >`
`class Binder1 : public Binder<std::result_of<func_t (param0_t)>::type>`

compile result: `expected a type, got std::result_of<func_t(param0_t)>::type’`

Comment: @Tim Unfortunately I can't test it at work (my compiler is to old) but can you try `std::result_of<func_t>::type` (without the argument) instead?

Comment: @Tim Should be `typename std::result_of<func_t(param0_t)>::type`

Comment: @Tim I'm a little bit curious, since you have `std::result_of` you should also have [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) which basically does what you want. Why not use that instead of implementing your own?

Comment: I am sorry, the code should be like this: `class Binder1 : public Binder<typename std::result_of<func_t (param0_t)>::type>`, with an `typename` at front. but this gives me: `error: function returning a function`...

Comment: @joachim-pileborg std::bind returns a things that depends not only on the return type of the binded function, but also on the parameter number

Comment: @Tim Try `func_t const&(param0_t)` as the signature. (Although I think you should be aware of what's going on, as you may instead want to decay the parameters that are deduced by your `bind`. In addition to that, `func_t const&(param0_t const&)` might be the signature you actually want.)

Comment: @joachim-pileborg I have to hurry to school.. sorry.. I'll try this as soon as I am back.