# Generic way to deduce the return type of a functor?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++11

This question is a follow-up of [How to deduce the type of the functor's return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005749/how-to-deduce-the-type-of-the-functors-return-value)
I'm reformulating it in a more abstract way.

Given the pseudocode of a template function

```
template <typename Arg, typename Fn>
auto ComputeSomething(Arg arg, Fn fn) -> decltype(<decl-expr>)
{
// do something
// ............
return fn(<ret-expr>)
}
```

where `<ret-expr>` is an arbitrary expression which involves `arg`, what shall I use for `<decl-expr>` to set the return type of `ComputeSomething` equal to the return type of the functor.

The functor may be a class, a lambda or a function pointer.

Partial solutions I found so far.

(a) The answer for my linked question done by ecatmur. Essentially, it is repeating the return statement in `<decl-expr>`. Problems: it is error-prone and wouldn't work if  contains local variables.

(b) It works only for function pointers

```
template <typename Arg, typename Ret>
Ret ComputeSomething(Arg arg, Ret(*fn)(Arg))
```

(c) It assumes that the argument of the functor is of type `Arg` (which may not hold in general) and requires `Arg` to be default-constructible

```
template <typename Arg, typename Fn>
auto ComputeSomething(Arg arg, Fn fn) -> decltype(fn(Arg())
```

(d) Using `std::declval` which is supposed to lift the default-constructible restriction, as suggested in [how to deduce the return type of a function in template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10293903/1345960). Could anybody explain how it works?

```
template <typename Arg, typename Fn>
auto ComputeSomething(Arg arg, Fn fn) -> decltype(fn(std::declval<Arg>())
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but AFAIK this is not possible, because the trailing return does not see the function template being defined, while the body does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my own solution, the best I could get

```
template <typename Arg, typename Fn>
typename std::result_of<Fn(Arg)>::type ComputeSomething(Arg arg, Fn fn)
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [result_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of). It is backwards compatible and takes all the ugly `declval` pain out of your code. You still need to remember to add rvalue reference qualifiers (`&&`) if you actually just forward values.

Something else I find important: Your function forwards arguments to another function. In such cases you should always use rvalue references to pass the arguments.

If all you are trying to do is improve maintainability: there are several attempts at a `RETURNS` macro around that try to minimize the repetition between the return type declaration and the actual return expression, but I haven't seen any that allows a function body that contains more than the actual return statement.

As for how `declval` works: Its compiler dependent. It isn't allowed to occur in an evaluated content and its argument can be an incomplete type. See [20.2.4](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval)

Comment: I would advise against `std::result_of`. For once it isn't guaranteed to SFINAE, unlike `decltype`-based solutions. It also doesn't reflect the result type of a call -- it does more than that e.g. in relation with pointers to members.

Comment: @LucDanton I always perceived "doing more" as a benefit. Handling the case of pointers to member functions is horribly tedious and `result_of` solves that problem. Can you go more into detail about the SFINAE issue?

Comment: There's no point in `std::result_of` computing a result type the function template can't deal with -- `f(a, b, c)` is a syntax error when `f` is a pointer to member. As for the SFINAE, consider an overloaded `apply` such that `apply(f, args...)` either results in `f(args...)` or, if it isn't well formed, resorts to `f(*args...)` (let's assume for the sake of simplicity that those two expressions are never simultaneously well-formed). You need SFINAE to remove either overload for a call to succeed.

Comment: @LucDanton Wouldn't you usually just dispatch on some kind of `call_traits` if you want to handle both raw member function pointer and normal functions or just require wrapping it in `mem_fn`. I'll probably have to work through the SFINAE part, because I don't get it.

Comment: This isn't about function pointers (and `std::mem_fn` doesn't help with that anyway). And the point is that if you use `decltype` then it just works.

Answer (score 11):

`std::declval` is a function template that is only declared (not defined). It can thus only be used in unevaluated contexts such as the argument to `sizeof` and `decltype`. It is declared to return an rvalue of the specified type. This allows you to use it to manufacture a dummy parameter for a function call in a `decltype` expression.

e.g.

```
typedef decltype(fn(std::declval<Arg>())) t;
```

declares `t` to be the type of the result of calling `fn` with an rvalue of type `Arg`. This is similar to your case (c) (`fn(Arg())`), but it doesn't require anything of `Arg`, so it works on types without default constructors.

If your return expression uses a local variable of type `foo`, then you can use `decltype(fn(std::declval<foo>()))`, again regardless of how you construct a `foo`.

If you need an lvalue, such as a named object or an lvalue reference, then you can use `std::declval<foo&>()`. This allows you to handle the case where the type depends on whether you have an lvalue or an rvalue.

Comment: `std::declval<Arg&>()` is also something to be considered, especially considering you mention a local variable.

Answer (score 3):

To make (c) works for anything, you need 2 overloads.  1st as shown in (c), 2nd:

```
template <typename Arg, typename Ret>
Ret ComputeSomething(Arg arg, std::function<Ret(Arg)> fn)
```

Also, as [gcc bug 54111](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54111) shows - deduction of return type is very unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

A variant of (b) working not only with function pointers should be something like

```
template<typename Arg, typename Ret>
Ret ComputeSomething (Arg arg, function<auto (Arg) -> Ret> f)
```